# VBA calling a function not directly using

Tags: vba, function

I have two functions. Users call first function (`FunctOne`), in Excel, and select a range of inputs an perform something. A second function (`FunctTwo`) uses this partial output and it performs something more. I want to show `FunctTwo` output.

My question is: how can I show the result of the `FunctTwo`? Do I need to create a third function? if yes, How does it look like?

Thanks a lot,

```
Function FunctOne(var1, var2 As Range)

Do something 'perform some calculations using inputs

End Function
```

===========

```
Function FunctTwo(FunctOne As Variant) As Variant

Do something 'use the output of FunctOne and do something

End Function
```

PD: I tried to do all in just one function, but the loop doesn't work as I expected. So, maybe if I change my approach using two functions it might work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not my downvote, but can you explain a bit more how `Opt` is related to `TirNoPer360`? I'm not sure what you mean by "This last step is performed by the second function (Opt) through simple try and error algo." I don't see that happening anywhere.

Comment: Please show how/when `Opt` is called.

Comment: @ja72 that's part of the question (how can I show the result of the Opt?).

Comment: @BigBen Sure. This a finding root algorithm. Function TirNoPer360 is what I try to optimize using Opt. The last step is the optimization per se (using a try-error) which is doing in Opt. I may be wrong of course since is what I am trying to verify.

Comment: `TirNoPer360 = Opt(sum)`? Your question is extremely unclear / hard to understand. I second @BigBen in requesting that you [edit] your post to clarify how `Opt` relates to the other function, since right now it reads essentially like "I have an apple and a banana, how do I get a banana-flavored orange by eating an apple".

Comment: In `TirNoPer360`, you `Dim Inicio As Date`, but you don't ever use it. You use `Initial`, but don't declare (`Dim`) it. You declare `n` and `j`, but don't use them. You have `Cash` as a parameter and treat it like a `Range`, but it's really a `Variant` - you should specify `As Range` in the parameter list if that's what you mean (`(Cash, Dates As Range)` declares a `Variant` and a `Range`, not 2 `Range`s).

Comment: In `opt`, I'm not sure what `funcion < -tolerance` is supposed to do. Is that supposed to be `tolerance * -1` (i.e. the negative of `tolerance`) or something totally different or is it a typo?

Comment: @FreeMan you are right. it is the negative of "tolerance"

Comment: I rewrite my question leaving the main idea.

Comment: You _cannot_ pass a function as a parameter to another function in VBA.

Comment: Well, OK, you cannot _easily_ or _natively_ pass a function as a parameter to another function without a lot of hacking and low level witchcraftery.

Comment: I think I found a solution to my problem. I set up FunctOne with var1 and var2. Then I set up FunctTwo with two new variables (that match those in FunctOne). And the magic was done. I think is the same @FreeMan wrote.

Comment: Use does the user use `FunctOne`? Do they enter it in a cell, or do they call it from another subroutine/function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to establish a sequence of computation that has to be done in a specific order then you need to create a subroutine that drives the computations.

```
Public Sub MyCalculations()
    Dim var1 as Range, var2 as Range

    var1 = ...
    var2 = ...
    Dim f1 as Variant
    f1 = FunctOne(var1, var2)

    Dim f2 as Variant
    f2 = FunctTwo(f1)

End Sub
```

**The above assumes that `FunctOne` and `FunctTwo` do not change the worksheet (not side effects assumption).** It is best practice to declare the arguments `ByVal` so that the functions cannot change any of the local variables used above.